# Anyone recognize this airport?

Tags: airport

I found this image on [boldmethod](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/FAA-SFAR-extension-past-june-30/).

Where is this? Looks like a beautiful place. Has an instrument approach (from the runway markings.) On a mesa in snow country. It is not Sedona or St George.

Telluride?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the picture from?

Comment: I found the image on [BoldMethod](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/FAA-SFAR-extension-past-june-30/). The credit is themselves, but I imagine an email to the article author might yield a result.

Comment: Please include source information in the post. @CatchAsCatchCan are you the same person as "dawg" the OP?

Comment: *@CatchAsCatchCan are you the same person as "dawg" * -- No, I am not @CatchAsCatchCan. I am sure he did a google image search. Yes, that is the source of that image.

Comment: @FreeMan No, I'm not dawg, and yes, I did a Google image search

Comment: Well done, then, @CatchAsCatchCan!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Telluride RWY 9, as can be seen clearly in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP_2ASzpPqA).

Screenshot from video:
[image]